# Como controlar Seeders no Laravel de forma parecida com as Migrations?

Tags: banco-de-dados, laravel

Eu tenho um controle de permissões no Laravel usando o Spatie. Está funcionando perfeitamente.

O problema é que a cada atualização podemos inserir permissões novas no sistema e, como temos ambiente de produção e de testes, temos que ficar inserindo manualmente as novas permissões em cada um desses ambientes e imagino que isso não é o ideal.

Minha ideia é ter algo como fazemos com as migrations, onde você, a cada atualização da estrutura das tabelas do seu banco, cria uma nova migration e apenas roda o comando `php artisan migrate`. Assim o artisan roda apenas o que ainda não foi rodado.

Existe a possibilidade disso com Seeders? Ou outra solução?

Não sei se é uma boa prática usar as migrations para essa finalidade, pois aprendi que elas devem mexer apenas com a estrutura das tabelas.

Estou utilizando Laravel 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro verificar via *Database Seeding* mesmo. Tem um método `firstOrCreate` que faz o cadastro da entidade (no caso a Permission ou Role) somente se não existir no banco de dados.

Talvez desta forma atenda sua necessidade, podendo sempre rodar o *Seed*, criando apenas o que é novo.

Documentação do laravel-permission (*Database Seeding*): https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/advanced-usage/seeding

Documentação do Laravel (firstOrCreate): https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models